# Python - Pip installing into directory where Python isn't installed

Tags: python, pip, package

Right now I have Python installed in **C:\Users\Jared\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39**. Pip is installing packages in **C:\Users\Jared\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages**. Does it matter that pip is installing into a different directory other than where Python is installed? I'm guessing if I want Pip to install packages where Python is installed I'd need to remove the Roaming path or modify USER_BASE and USER_SITE to the Local path. Below is my sys.path.

```
C:\Users\Jared>python -m site
sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\Jared',
    'C:\\Users\\Jared\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\Jared\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Users\\Jared\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\Jared\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
    'C:\\Users\\Jared\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Users\\Jared\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: 'C:\\Users\\Jared\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python' (exists)
USER_SITE: 'C:\\Users\\Jared\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--install-option` to multiple times to add any of the options you can use with python `setup.py` install( `--prefix` is probably what you want, but there are a bunch more options you could use). But you still need to add `d:\somewhere\other\than\the\default to PYTHONPATH` to actually use them from that location.